# SAPUI5 Table shows data only on ABAP Server?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have created a simple UI5 application which consists of a Table.

The problem is that this table shows data only when I run the application on ABAP Server on other servers, ie. Tomcat or Web App Preview in eclipse it doesn't work. I also tried this application with other open oData services but the table shows no result.

Secondly the table show the data and after it continue to scroll down the data and there comes empty fields from above and data disappears to the down.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Your first problem is most likely a cross-origin issue; check your console log for the error. Regarding the empty fields, it's impossible to give an answer without some code snippets

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you will be helped with disabeling the same origin policy in google chrome. See:
[Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome).

For a more extensive answer see:
http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2013/06/29/solving-same-origin-policy-issue-in-different-ways

Answer (score 0):

That usually happened to me when I didn't map the correct field to the "Items" of the table.
You must check both the capitalization and the path of the item in your model.

Here is a short example :

```
             <Table id="idMaterialsList2"
                    items="{SalesOrder>/Items/results}">
                <columns>
                    <Column>
                        <Text text="{i18n>Order_product}" />
                    </Column>
                </columns>
                <items>
                    <ColumnListItem type="Navigation">
                        <ObjectIdentifier
                            title="{SalesOrder>Product}"
                            text="{SalesOrder>Description}"/>
                    </ColumnListItem>
                </items>
             </Table>
```

a) Check "`items="{SalesOrder>/Items/results}"`" the path

b) Check the names of the elements you want to show "`"{SalesOrder>Product}"`"

If a is correct and b is wrong you will have an empty table with X lines where X = `SalesOrder>/Items/results.length`.
If a is wrong you will see nothing.

Try :)